# Retrieve database value based on year?

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I have a table named as `holidays` i want to filter the row based on the year. My database table look like this,

```
 2013-09-25

 2013-09-12

 2014-01-15

 2014-05-15
```

i want only the column values whose year starts with `2013`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
  holidays
WHERE
  YEAR(`date_field`) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM holidays
WHERE YEAR(date_field) LIKE '%2013%'
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f588/5)